# Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to loop through an array to check if it contains any item that passes a specified function. I do this by adding a .any() prototype to the Array object:

```
Array.prototype.any = (comparator) => {
    for(let item of this){
        if(comparator(item)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Then calling Array.any() like:

```
else if(users && users.any((user) => user.userName === user.userName)){
        res.status(400).send('Username already in use');
}
```

This however gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
at Array.any (C:\dev\nodejs\testproject\dist\routes\userRoutes.js:29:39)
at C:\dev\nodejs\testproject\dist\routes\userRoutes.js:87:56
at Query.<anonymous> (C:\dev\nodejs\testproject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3748:16)
at C:\dev\nodejs\testproject\node_modules\kareem\index.js:277:21
at C:\dev\nodejs\testproject\node_modules\kareem\index.js:131:16
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

The error seems to me like it is suggesting 'this' in the prototype function is undefined, but 'this' is the users array for which i checked for undefined.

Not realy sure what is actually causing the issue, hope you can help.

Comment: What is "users"? It would appear not to be an array but is rather a `Query` object from mongoose. I think you did something like `var users = User.find({})`. Yes?

Comment: `user.userName === user.userName`: do you really mean that?

Comment: You could be correct here "users" is indeed comming from mongoose

Comment: `User.find({}, (err, users) => {
        if(err) res.send(500);

        else if(users && users.any((user) => user.userName === user.userName)){
            res.status(400).send('Username already in use');
        }

        else{
            done(user);
        }
    });

Comment: Also, can't you just use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control)?

Comment: @IdsvanderZee Edit your question and show the actual code around this. Also explain what you think your `any` method is supposed to achieve. I think you should be instead using a "query condition" for what you want. But we need your edit to explain.

Comment: It indeed apears Array.prototype.some() will achieve the same thing here, also `user.userName === user.userName` was a mistake it should have been `user1.userName === user.userName`

Comment: It basically "looks like" you just want `User.find({ "userName": inputUserName }).limit(1).exec(err, user) { .... if (user) { //user found })` as the shorthand form of the logic. So if something was actually returned by the query, then the username exists already.

Comment: Yes changed it to `const checkUniqueUserName = (user, res, done) => {
    User.findOne({"userName": user.userName}, (err, user) => {
        if(err) res.send(500);

        else if(user){
            res.status(400).send('Username already in use');
        }

        else{
            done(user);
        }
    });
};` It seems to be working now

Comment: @IdsvanderZee Please add that as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) then, not by editing your question - which completely invalidated the error message.

Comment: @Bergi I added the answer, but my edit of the question did not include the answer or changed the result. The edit I made fixed a few other issues that were "unrelated" to the question, after my edit the same error would have still persisted. The actual answer is in the comment of Neil Lunn or at least for the most part.

Comment: @IdsvanderZee Thanks, but the edit did at least remove the code that was mentioned in the error message, that's why I reverted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only answer here is that you didn't use "function", so your "this" is not your "users". This would work:

```
Array.prototype.any = function(comparator) {
    for(let item of this){
        if(comparator(item)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

And then, of course, just use "some".

Answer (score 2):

Using Array.prototype.any() was unnecesary as I was using mongoose to get the users so I changed it to have mongoose try to get a single user that has the secified username and checking if that was defined. Like:

```
const checkUniqueUserName = (user, res, done) => {
    User.findOne({"userName": user.userName}, (err, foundUser) => {
        if(err){
            res.sendStatus(500);
            console.log(err);
        }

        else if(foundUser){
            res.status(400).send('Username already in use');
        }

        else{
            done(user);
        }
    });
};
```